# SASS: Conditional values of CSS property based on that if an element with certain value of the same property has been present already in the page

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I want to have different values of a css property (I am using SASS), based on that whether a element with a certain property's value '*$additionalNavHeight*' is present on the page. In some pages there is no such element, in other - there is. I wrote a SASS mixin:

```
@mixin top-position($navHeight, $additionalNavHeight)
{ 
  @if $additionalNavHeight == true {
    .loadingAnimation {
      top: $navHeight + $additionalNavHeight;
    }
  } 
  @else {
    .loadingAnimation {
      top: $navHeight;
    }
  }
}
```

And I included the mixin in the selector:

```
@include top-position($navHeight, $additionalNavHeight);
```

I thought this should change the value of the property '*top*'  of the element with the class '*loadingAnimation*', based on that if in the page already is present the element with the value of its '*top*' property '$additionalNavHeight'. The compiler doesn't show any error, but the code doesn't change anything. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: By “present on the page” you mean if such an element exists _anywhere_ in the DOM? // Your SASS is compiled long before it even gets applied to any “page”, so how do you expect that to work?

Comment: Sounds more of a JavaScript/JQuery job rather than CSS

Comment: The idea is that I have to add the conditional css value of the element when the page is already loaded. The animation happens on click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тhe simplest solution. You must check with JavaScript if element exists or not 
and to apply the second class to element. In the second case (element existing) 
you must add adittionnal height. In this case the mixin is redundant.

```
   .loadingAnimation {
      top: $navHeight;
    }
    .loadingAnimation.additinnalHeight {
      top: $navHeight + $additionalNavHeight;
    }
```

Here is example jsfiffle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ra9r8rk8/
In this case element will receive class newClass when the first div exists. (the element)

Edit: This is second improved solution. In fact there is no need for regular expression. We can just use classList: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ra9r8rk8/1/

Comment: It worked perfectly! That was exactly what I needed!